# Sum values from a JSON with Symfony QueryBuilder

Tags: mysql, json, symfony, query-builder

I have an issue with a query suming values stored in a Json array.
I have a Sheet entity that is joined with a Valid entity. Valid has a field "$dac" corresponding to the Json array. Here is an example of what the Json can look like.

```
{
  "bdc": {
    "service": {
       "operator": {
              "entries": [
                 {
                "priceDF": 100,
                "priceWT": 150,
                "firstNumber": 12,
                "paymentDate": {
                "date": "2023-08-07 00:00:00.000000",
                   "timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
                   "timezone_type": 3
                 },
                "secondNumber": 23,
                "paymentNumber": 1212,
                "dateFirstNumber": {
                   "date": "2023-08-07 00:00:00.000000",
                   "timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
                   "timezone_type": 3
                 }
                },
                {
                "priceDF": 100,
                "priceWT": 250,
                "firstNumber": 13,
                "paymentDate": {
                "date": "2023-08-07 00:00:00.000000",
                  "timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
                  "timezone_type": 3
                 },
                 "secondNumber": 24,
                 "paymentNumber": 1213,
                 "dateFirstNumber": {
                 "date": "2023-08-07 00:00:00.000000",
                    "timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
                    "timezone_type": 3
                  }
               }
            ]
      }
    },
    
       },
  "step": "Paiement",
  "type": "bdc",
  "anticipated": false
}
```

I actually want to sum up the values "priceDF" that are in the objects stored in the "entries" array (path : sheet.valid.dac.bdc.service.operator.entries).

I tried to write this query:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');
$qb->select("SUM(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(v.dac, '$.bdc.service.operator.entries[*].priceWT') AS     DECIMAL(10,2)) ) as totalPriceWT")
->join('s.valid', 'v')
$query = $qb->getQuery();
$resultCP = $query->getResult();
```

but it always returns 0. I fact I'm sure that writing entries[*].priceWT doesn't work but I don't know how to do it anyway.

Does anyone know how to sum up values in this kind of Json ? Thanks you.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Version 8.0.33 for Linux Ubuntu

Comment: Try: `$qb->select("(SELECT SUM(\`priceWT\`) FROM JSON_TABLE(JSON_EXTRACT(\`v\`.\`dac\`, '$.bdc.service.operator.entries[*].priceWT'), '$[*]' COLUMNS(\`priceWT\` DECIMAL(10, 2) PATH '$')) \`der\`) AS \`totalPriceWT\`")...`. See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KJhIBy6J).

Comment: I'm using the ScientaNL/DoctrinejsonFunctions that are extensions to Doctrine to use json query functions. Unfortunately it doesn't provide the JSON_TABLE function so this query  won't work in my project.
Available functions that I can use for mysql:
[DoctrineJsonFunctions GitHub](https://github.com/ScientaNL/DoctrineJsonFunctions)
Do you think that suming up values directly in a php foreach() will take significantly more time than a SQL query ?

Comment: The time it takes in PHP, in part, will depend on the number of records to summarize (millions?, billions?), in PHP you have the [array_sum](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) function (as an option). To use `JSON_TABLE`, you can also run raw SQL in Doctrine, see [Data Retrieval And Manipulation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/current/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#data-retrieval-and-manipulation), always taking care of security holes (SQL injection).

Comment: Thank you I eventually used a raw SQL query in order to do what I want and it works perfectly with the query you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @wchiquito the query works perfectly. I added other conditions to meet my project requirements, here is the final query (PHP):

```
$sql = " SELECT
              SUM(sub.totalPriceWT) AS totalPrice,
              c.label
          FROM (
              SELECT
                  v.id,
                  (
                      SELECT SUM(priceWT)
                      FROM JSON_TABLE(
                          JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(v.dac, '$.bdc.service.operator.entries[*].priceWT')),
                          '$[*]' COLUMNS(priceWT DECIMAL(10, 2) PATH '$')
                      ) der
                  ) AS totalPriceWT
              FROM valid v
              JOIN sheet s ON v.sheet_id = s.id
              WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(v.dac, '$.type')) = 'bdc'
                  AND (
                      (YEAR(s.sent_date) = :currentYear AND CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(v.dac, '$.anticipated') AS SIGNED) = :anticipated2)
                      OR
                      (YEAR(s.sent_date) = :previousYear AND CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(v.dac, '$.anticipated') AS SIGNED) = :anticipated1)
                  )
                  AND s.perimeter_id = :perimeter
                  AND JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(v.dac, '$.bdc.service.operator.entries')) IS NOT NULL
          ) AS sub
          JOIN valid v2 ON sub.id = v2.id
          JOIN sheet s2 ON v2.sheet_id = s2.id
          JOIN cost_center c ON s2.cost_center_id = c.id
          GROUP BY c.id
          ";

  $conn = $this->manager->getConnection();
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindValue('perimeter', $perimeter->getId());
  $stmt->bindValue('currentYear', $year);
  $stmt->bindValue('previousYear', $year - 1);
  $stmt->bindValue('anticipated1', 1);
  $stmt->bindValue('anticipated2', 0);
  $resultSet = $stmt->executeQuery();
  $resultBDC = $resultSet->fetchAllAssociative();
```